# MacBook Cut function acting oddly

Tags: mac, keyboard

This problem started happening today. When using <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> using the Left <kbd>command</kbd> key, there seems to be no response from the Mac.

(Note: this is for cutting and pasting text.)

However, when using the Right Command key for cutting text, things seem to be working just fine.

The Left Command Key works fine when using any other Key combinations such as <kbd>command</kbd> + Space, <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> .

The Left Command on its own is working fine, just not with <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>

I haven't been able to pinpoint the issue yet, I tried a restart, but nothing yet. I'll post an update once I try clearing PRAM and SMC.

**Update**
Cleared PRAM / SMC.. No luck.

**Update 2**
I noticed that <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> just does not register at all if I press the Left Command key...

Comment: Some vintages of keyboard seem to get sticky keys at random times  (https://www.cnet.com/how-to/this-is-the-best-way-to-unstick-a-stuck-macbook-keyboard/) - are you sure it's working for the other combinations..  I have a number of MBP where the left command key doesn't always work [it does if you click perfectly straight and are "deliberate" about it] - whereas the right (less used one) is mostly problem free.  They "feel" different when they don't work..   In your case I wonder if it is different angle of pressure for CmdX vs CmdC/V??

Comment: @MrR Yes, different key combinations work just fine, CmdC and CmdV work fine. I tried using an event viewer and Cmd on its own works too! X on its own also works.

Comment: It's just the combination of Cmd + X where the problem is...